# Prove the absolute value is a sobolev function

Tags: integration, sobolev-spaces

> Definition. A function $u$ has weak derivative $v \in L^1_{\text{loc}}$ if for any $C^1$ function $\phi$ with compact support we have
> $$
> -\int_U v(x)\,\phi(x)\, \mathrm{d}x = \int_U u(x)\,\phi'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.
> $$

> Definition. $u$ is called a Sobolev function (in the one-dimensional case) if its weak derivative exists.

Let $u:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $u(x):=|x|$ be the absolute value on the real numbers. I'm looking for functions $\phi$ ($C^1$ and with compact support) and $v$ (locally integrable) such that on finite subsets $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
\int_U (v(x)\,\phi(x) + u(x)\,\phi'(x))\,\mathrm{d}x = 0.
$$

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Take $\phi = 0$ ...

Comment: @LL3.14 Yes trivially the zero function works. But I wonder how one finds a nontrivial example (I am willing to work out the details myself, but have really no clue how one attacks this problem and very thankful for hints…) :D

Comment: $v(x)=\mbox{sign}\, x$, that is,  $v(x)=-1$ if $x<0$ and $v(x)=+1$ if $x>0$.

Comment: and the first definition is incorrect. You need to show that it is true for *any* $C^1$ and compactly supported $\phi$.

Comment: @Artem Thank you ;)

Comment: So I suppose you are rather looking for a function $v$ such that **for any** $\phi$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the "intuitive" idea that the derivative of $|x|$ is probably $\operatorname{sign}(x)$, i.e.

$$v(x) = \operatorname{sign}(x):=\begin{cases} 1 &: x\geq 0 \\ -1 &: x <0.\end{cases}$$

Then, for any $\phi\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$, one has:

\begin{align}\int\limits_\mathbb{R} \phi'(x) \cdot |x|dx&= \int\limits_0^\infty\phi'(x) \cdot xdx - \int\limits_{-\infty}^0 \phi'(x) \cdot xdx\\
& = [\phi(x)\cdot x]_0^\infty-\int\limits_0^\infty \phi(x)\cdot 1 dx - [\phi(x)\cdot x]_0^\infty -\int\limits_{-\infty}^0\phi(x)\cdot (-1)dx\\
&=-\int\limits_\mathbb{R} \phi(x) \cdot v(x) dx
\end{align}
In the second equation, one uses partial integration, and for the third equation, one uses that $\phi$ has compact support, i.e. $\phi(\pm\infty)=0$ and also of course that $\phi(0)-\phi(0)=0$.

Comment: Aaaah yes okay, I see. But is there a general strategy to prove this for other functions $u$?

Comment: @PhilippeKnecht There is no general strategy that always works, but using partial integration is a good starting point - in principle, that is where the definition of the weak derivative comes from.

Comment: You can also often compute the derivative in almost all points, and deduce what could be the function $v$ like that